# How can I pass my login details to a web page?

Tags: python, web, authentication, mechanize

```
<div class="group group-form group-form-requiredinformation">
    <h2 class="sr">Required Information</h2>

    <ol class="list-input">
      <li class="field required text" id="field-email">
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input class="" id="email" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="example: username@domain.com" required aria-required="true" aria-described-by="email-tip" />
        <span class="tip tip-input" id="email-tip">This is the e-mail address you used to register with edX</span>
      </li>
      <li class="field required password" id="field-password">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="" required aria-required="true" />
        <span class="tip tip-input">
```

I am trying to write some code that will parse a webpage and check for updated content periodically, my problem is that I need to be logged in but I am unsure how to pass in my login details, the above is some of the source of the login page, how is it possible to achieve this?

I have tried something like the code below but to no avail.

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open("https:xxxx")
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form['username'] = "email"
browser.form['password'] = "xxxxx"
browser.submit()
```

Comment: Doesn't the site have an API you can query instead? This is quite a bit more involved than you seem to think.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, I have not done this before so I have no idea what is involved, it is for an edx course so I am not sure if they do.

Comment: Submitting the form values as you have is merely verifying the credentials with the server. It does nothing to maintain the login session. There will likely be, at minimum, cookie values returned that you need to store and sent with each future request.

Comment: The only time I have done anything web related I was using the betfair api where I used json and requests to store a sessionToken and sent keep alives to stay logged in, will a similar approach work with this or am I way off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least, the field is called `email`, not `username`:

```
browser.form['email'] = "email"
browser.form['password'] = "xxxxx"
browser.submit()
```

Comment: thanks,that has gotten me a step further, I am getting an error about no control matching name password but I will figure it out once I know I am on somewhat the right lines.

Comment: I seem to remember using some tool that used to highlight corresponding source code to actual parts of a web page,like when you focused the login box it would highlight that code that corresponded . Do you know of anything like this or am I confused with something else?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yup, you can use browser developer tools, e.g. chrome developer tools - it's pretty powerful.

Answer (score -1):

store the last updated date time in a variable and have a javascript timer function to invoke a function to check the last updated date time and if the content was updated more than the predefined time, make a call to backend and update the info on the page.

FYI.. there is no browser object. there is document object which has properties and methods to manipulate the page

Comment: Please read the question more closely. This is not what Padraic is asking about, nor the language, environment being used.

Comment: Andrew, sorry i was not aware of a library called mechanize.. i should have read the question properly.